# Maven Build failure in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

While running a build in Jenkins Maven is complaining about JDK. I know very well that it's some challenge with env variables. I have set JAVA_HOME to JDK installation path but no luck. I have searched the whole web and know that other people have faced this but their solution isn't working for me. Any help would be really appreciated !

```
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
```

FYR, my maven version output.

```
root@zarvis:~# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-31-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

JAVA_HOME is set but not sure why maven appends it with JRE.

```
root@zarvis:~# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding JDK_HOME to your path

Comment: Did the same but same error persists.

root@zarvis:~# echo $JAVA_HOME && echo $JDK_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME directing to the jre folder? 
If so, it shouldn't

Comment: try running export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/
If it works - you can also add this line to your ~/.bashrc file.